# Why std::find doesn't work on std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, find, shared-ptr

We came across something we can not explain at work, and even if we found a solution, i would like to know exactly why the first code was fishy.

Here a minimal code example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> r;

    r.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(42));
    r.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(1337));
    r.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(13));
    r.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(37));

    int* s = r.back().get();

    auto it = std::find(r.begin(),r.end(),s); // 1 - compliation error
    auto it = std::find(r.begin(),r.end(),std::shared_ptr<int>(s)); // 2 - runtime error
    auto it = std::find_if(r.begin(),r.end(),[s](std::shared_ptr<int> i){
    return i.get() == s;}
    ); // 3 -works fine

    if(it == r.end())
        cout << "oups" << endl;
    else
        cout << "found" << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

So what i want to know is why the find are not working.

1. For the first one, it seems that shared_ptr do not have [a comparison operator with raw pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp), can someone explain why ?
2. The second one seems to be a problem of ownership, multiple delete (when my local shared_ptr goes out of scope it delete my pointer), but what i don't understand is why the runtime error is during the find execution, the double delete should happen only on the vector destruction, any thoughts ?

I have the working solution with the find_if so what i really want is to understand why the first two are not working, not another working solution (but if you have a more elegant one, feel free to post).

Comment: Option 2 is bad, don't do it. It may lead to double free. About 1, shared pointer doesn't support comparision with raw pointer for similar reason. If an address is wrapped in a shared pointer, it is not supposed to be used in a naked pointer as it may accidentally lead to double delete. If naked (raw) pointers are not exposed, there is no point of providing comparision operator. p.s. `get()` is available only to support legacy apis.

Comment: If you'd written `std::shared_ptr<int> s = r.back();`, then your first version would have worked.  If you're going to use `std::shared_ptr` to an object, then _all_ pointers to that object should be `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes i know, but in the original code, pointers are used. But thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the first one, it seems that shared_ptr do not have a comparison
>   operator with raw pointers, can someone explain why ?

Subjective, but I certainly don't consider it a good idea for shared pointers to be comparable to raw pointers, and I think the authors of `std::shared_ptr` and the standard's committee agree with that sentiment.

> The second one seems to be a problem of ownership, multiple delete
>   (when my local shared_ptr goes out of scope it delete my pointer), but
>   what i don't understand is why the runtime error is during the find
>   execution, the double delete should happen only on the vector
>   destruction, any thoughts ?

`s` is a pointer to an `int` that was allocated by `make_shared` as part of a block, together with the reference counting information. It's implementation defined how it actually was allocated, but you can be sure it was not with a simple unadorned new expression, because that would allocate a seperate int in its own memory location. i.e. it was not allocated in any of these ways:

```
p = new int;
p = new int(value);
p = new int{value};
```

Then you passed `s` to the constructor of a new `shared_ptr` (the `shared_ptr` you passed as an argument to `std::find`). Since you didn't pass a special deleter along with the pointer, the default deleter will be used. The default deleter will simply call `delete` on the pointer.

Since the pointer was *not* allocated with an unadorned new expression, calling `delete` on it is undefined behavior. Since the temporary `shared_ptr` will be destroyed at the end of the statement, and it believes it is the sole owner of the integer, `delete` will be called on the integer at the end of the statement. This is likely the cause of your runtime error.

Try the following, easier to reason about snippet, and you will likely run into the same problem:

```
auto p = std::make_shared<int>(10);
delete p.get();  // This will most likely cause the same error.
                 // It is undefined behavior though, so there
                 // are no guarantees on that.
```

Comment: @Jarod42: Okay, acually, I don't know what the word is I'm looking for. But it's the non-placement new expression, which make_shared certainly does not use.  Hold on, I'll figure out the correct wording.

Comment: +1 It was *very* interesting seeing how this is done in the clang implementation on my Mac. Does *anyone* write standard library code that is *readable* without caffeine ? It was particularly interesting to see that (at least on my Mac), to indicate the shared pointer reference data block also contained the shared resource (i.e. not a separate pointer), *both* the strong *and* weak attribute bits were set. Heh. I guess that's one way to do it

Comment: +1 I understand the origin of the runtime error now. Thanks for pointing out and explaining this UB that i did not see.

Answer (score 2):

The smart pointer class template `std::shared_ptr<>` only supports operators for comparison against other `std::shared_ptr<>` objects; not raw pointers. Specifically, these are supported in that case:

```
operator==    - Equivalence
operator!=    - Negated equivalence
operator<     - Less-than
operator<=    - Less-than or equivalent
operator>     - Greater-than
operator>=    - Greater-than or equivalent
```

[**Read here for more info**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp)

Regarding *why* in the first case, because it isn't just a question of *value*; its a question of equivalence. A `std::shared_ptr<>` cannot be considered equivalent or comparable to a raw address simply because that raw address may *not* be held within a shared pointer. And even if the addresses *are* value equivalent, that doesn't mean the source of the latter came from a properly reference-counted equivalence (i.e. another shared pointer). Interestingly, your second example exposes what happens when you try to rig that system.

Regarding the second case, constructing a shared pointer as you are will proclaim two independent shared pointers having  independent ownership of the *same* dynamic resource. So ask yourself, which one gets to *delete* it ? Um... yeah. Only when you replicate the `std::shared_ptr<>` itself will the reference count material shared among shared pointers holding the same datum reference be properly managed, so your code in this case is just-plain *wrong*.

If you want to hunt a raw address down in a collection of shared pointers, your third method is *exactly* how you should do it.

**Edit: Why does the ownership issue in case 2 render where it does?**

Ok, I did some hunting, and it turns out its a runtime-thing (at least on my implementation). I would have to check to know for sure if this behavior (of `std::make_shared`) is hardened in the standard, but I doubt it). The bottom line is this. These two things:

```
r.push_back(new int(42));
```

and

```
r.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(42));
```

can do *very* different things. The former dynamically allocates a new `int`, then send its address off to the matching constructor for `std::shared_ptr<iint>`, which allocates its *own* shared reference data that manages referencing counting to the provided address. I.e. there are *two* distinct blocks of data from separate allocations.

But the latter does something different. It allocates the object *and* the shared reference data in the *same memory block*, using placement-new for the object itself and either move-construction or copy-construction depending on what is provided/appropriate. The result is there is **one** memory allocation, and it holds *both* the reference data *and* the object, the latter being an offset within the allocate memory. Therefore the pointer you're sending to your shared_ptr did not come from an allocation return value.

Try the first one, and i bet you'll see you're runtime error relocate to the destruction of the vector rather then the conclusion of the find.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For 2, I understand why this is wrong, but I wonder why the runtime error is in the find execution, during that time, at most one shared_ptr is deleted (the temporary one), so UB will come when the second one is deleted, so when vector goes out of scope. But this is not what happen, so there is something I don't get here.

Comment: Ah.. now *that* is an interesting question (and ironic considering it comes from a case of UB, don't you think?). You may find your answer by wrapping your shared pointer in an object who's constructor/destructor logic you can debug-print. I think it may be rather telling to see what is created, destroyed, and most importantly, *when*.

Answer (score 1):

1. `bool operator ==(const std::shared_ptr<T>&, const T*)` doesn't exist.
2. It is a bad usage of `std::shared_ptr`
   it is like you do:

   ```
   int* p = new int(42);
   std::shared_ptr<int> sp1(p);
   std::shared_ptr<int> sp2(p); // Incorrect, should be sp2(sp1)
   // each sp1 and sp2 will delete p at end of scope -> double delete ...
   ```